# javascript array.length does not return number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code: `var a = rfc();`

`rfc()` returns an array expected in following format `{usd:1,gbp:0.59,bdt:77.5}`. I need to count it. I failed to do that using `a.length` . It always returns 0. I have checked the contents of a using the function below and the return was as follows:

function to check array contents:

```
Object.keys(coordinates).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, coordinates[key]);
});
```

Output at console:

```
usd 1
bdt 77.5
gbp 0.59
undefined
```

Why can't I get the array length using `array.length` and How can I count the number of elements of this array with minimum amount of codes?

Comment: Simply, it is not an array. It is an object.

Comment: _"returns an array expected in following format `{usd:1,gbp:0.59,bdt:77.5}`"_: you realise that's an object, not an array, right?

Comment: @Callie : length() is not a function

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object, and it has no length, so no suprise there

Comment: @all , Yeah, I realize that now. I am with PHP background and was thinking this might be some sort of associative array. Thanks a lot. Got the answer.

Comment: I think this is a fair question; there is often confusion between arrays and objects, particularly in javascript, and since the assignment syntax is so similar (a[0], a["zero"], a.zero), it's not always clear that this thing is no longer an object/array. Even `typeof` doesn't distinguish between arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript:

```
{usd:1, gbp:0.59, bdt:77.5}
```

represents an object, not an array. So it doesn't have a length property. To count the number of properties in your object very quickly, you can do:

```
var a = {usd:1,gbp:0.59,bdt:77.5}
var b = Object.keys(a).length
```

`b` will now be set to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Object.keys(coordinates).length
```

The original object is an object, not an array. However, in extracting an array of the keys of the object (as you do in `Object.keys(coordinates)` already), you have an array you can take the length of.

```
> a = {usd:1,gbp:0.59,bdt:77.5};
[object Object] {
 bdt: 77.5,
 gbp: 0.59,
 usd: 1
}

> Object.keys(a)
["usd", "gbp", "bdt"]

> Object.keys(a).length
3
```

Comment: I am with PHP background and was thinking this might be some sort of associative array. Thanks a lot. Got the answer.

Comment: @origin: I suspected it was a language thing, and of course in PHP the distinction is even less clear. For reference to help the site work, if an answer is the one that best answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick (can be changed later), and upvote any answers that are helpful.